# Riesz Representation Theorem in a compact space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

What simplifications would be found going through the proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem assuming the space X to be compact (or even compact metric) rather than just locally compact?

(I'm following the Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis)

I think that the possible situations in which simplifications could be found are:

1. If X is a Hausdorff compact space, a subset is compact if and only if it is closed. Every continuous function would have a compact support, as the support of a function is always closed, and hence (in this case), compact.
2. Every closed set would be in $\mathcal M_F$.
3. All the closed sets would be in $\mathcal M$, as $\mathcal M_F\subset \mathcal M$. As $\mathcal M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, all the open sets would be also in it.

I guess there are more possible simplifications, but I don't know how to find them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the proof of this [Riesz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) hard ? For $\psi \in C_c(X)'$ non-negative for non-negative functions, take (if possible) a sequence $f_{A,n}\in C_c(\Omega)$ decreasing to $1_A$ and set $\mu(A) = \lim \psi(f_{A,n})$, then show $\psi$ is given by $\mu$